# Tab Panel in gwt-ext

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

Hello all
I am using Tab Panel (With single tab). 
In this Tab Panel I am adding another Tab Panel (With single tab).
In the above Tab Panel I am adding another Tab Panel. (With 15 tab).

And for third & inner most Tab Panel I used auto horizontal tab scroll true. Like this :

taskTabPanel.setEnableTabScroll(true);

There are 15 tabs in the inner most tab.
Now my problem is that while clicking on the Right Horizontal scroll button It will work fine for 12 tab. (i.e It will scroll up to 12 tab correctly),But after 12th tab it is not scrolling properly.
Can any one help me out of this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello all 
I solved this issue.I am not getting what is th actual problem But what i did I am describing here.
Width of  inner most Tab Panel (with 15 tab) is set to 100%.
I changed it to in pixel (to 750px).
Now its working fine.